# Snowflake Connection in Python MemoryError

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, conda, snowflake-connector

I'm trying to establish a snowflake connection using Python in a Jupyter Notebook and am consistently getting the same error.

I am operating on a Mac M1, Python 3.10.4, and conda 4.13.0

Below is what I use to establish the connection after setting up my environment labels:

```
connection = snow.connect(user = user, password = password, account = '****.us-****-*', warehouse = 'COMPUTE_WH', authenticator = authenticator)
```

After, I get the following:

```
Initiating login request with your identity provider. A browser window should have opened for you to complete the login. If you can't see it, check existing browser windows, or your OS settings. Press CTRL+C to abort and try again...
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)

*rest of error*

MemoryError: Cannot allocate write+execute memory for ffi.callback(). You might be running on a system that prevents this. For more information, see https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html#callbacks
```

Would greatly appreciate any help at all on this!

Comment: What are you passing as the authenticator value? Is it okta?

Comment: Hi! My authenticated value is ‘external browser’

Comment: Can you share more of the code?

Answer (score 0):

I've run into similar issues.

Check the following:

- You are running snowflake connector and related in a virtual environment
- Is your account format missing host name?

  1. ex: company.loc-us-xx.**azure**
- You were able to use pip to install in the environment (connector does not agree with conda)
- Use an environment file like the one below to ensure pip is trusted.

[Example YML file with missing requirements for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuKZp.png)